# Variable Substitution

Tags: shell, variable-substitution

I have a variable assigned to a returned string:

`ytd_wk=$(cat file.csv | grep $(date +'%Y') | tail -1)`

I want to substring last 2 characters:

`ytd_wk=${ytd_wk:(-2)}`

Is there any way to use one-liner to achieve this? I have tried below but got `bad substitution` error:

`ytd_wk=${$(cat file.csv | grep $(date +'%Y') | tail -1):(-2)}`

Comment: How do you define “one-liner”?  You could just put your first two commands together on one line, separated by ``&&`` or ``;``.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to use:

```
grep "$(date +'%Y')" file.csv | tail -1 | sed 's/.*\(..$\)/\1/'
```

You don't need `cat` because `grep` can get data both from output of another program or from certain file. The last method more efficient because it uses only one command and this is more fast and consume less system resources.

The full solution:

```
ytd_wk=$(grep "$(date +'%Y')" file.csv | tail -1 | sed 's/.*\(..$\)/\1/')
```

You can omit `tail` with GNU `sed '$!d'`:

```
grep "$(date +'%Y')" file.csv | sed -r '$!d;s/.*(..$)/\1/'
```

POSIX:

```
grep "$(date +'%Y')" file.csv | sed -e '$!d' -e 's/.*\(..$\)/\1/'
```

Comment: +1 for not using `cat` in your answer — although it would have been better it you had explained *why* `cat` is unnecessary.

Answer (score 1):

You could use `awk`, combining the `cat`, `grep`, `sed`, and `tail` of other suggestions:

```
awk -v year=$(date +'%Y') '$0 ~ year {line=$0} END {print substr(line,length(line)-1,2)}' file.csv
```

Writing this out step-by-step

- `-v year=$(date +'%Y')` sets the `awk` variable `year` to the current year
- `$0 ~ year { line=$0 }` this is applied to each line of the file in turn. If there is a match to the year in the current line it saves it in the `awk` variable `line`
- `END { print substr(line,length(line)-1,2) }` at the end of the file (after the last line has been read and processed) this prints the last two characters of the most recently saved line. It prints a blank line if there was no earlier successful match.

Answer (score 1):

This is more efficient, especially if *file.csv* is large and the desired line is nearer to the end:

```
ytd_wk="$(tac file.csv | grep -m 1 $(date +'%Y') | grep -o '..$')"
```

How it works:  `tac` outputs *file.csv* backwards, and `grep -m 1` finds the first instance of the pattern, which is fed to `grep -o` which outputs only the last two chars.